# $A,B$ are $l \times m $ matrices of rank $l.$ Then there is an invertible matrix $P$ such that $AP=B,$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, field-theory, linear-transformations

Let $l \leq m$ are positive integers and $A$ and $B$ are two $l \times m$ matrices over a field $\mathbb{F}.$ If $\text{rank}(A)=\text{rank}(B)=l$ then I have to show that there is an $m \times m$ invertible matrix  $P$ over $\mathbb{F}$ such that $AP = B.$

I have no idea how to start it. I need some help. Thanks.

Comment: Are the matrices having same rank congruent ?? If yes, then the problem can be solved easily.

Comment: yes, rank same will imply congruent, then how this can be solved easily  ?

Comment: Then you can transform $A$ into $B$ by multiplying elementary matrices, and elementary matrices are invertible !! :D

Comment: how will I get that form ? remember row operations corresponds to premultiply !

Comment: And column operations correspond to post-multiplication !!

Comment: will be happy if you write a proof.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I forgot that congruence means simultaneous row-and-column operations, not some row or column equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reduced row echelon form of $A^T$ must be $\displaystyle R = \begin{pmatrix}I_{l\ \times\ l} \\ 0_{m - l\ \times\ l}\end{pmatrix}$, because the columns of $A^T$ are linearly independent. The same is true of $B^T$. Thus there are invertible matrices $P_A$ and $P_B$ such that
$$P_A A^T = R \text{ and }P_B B^T = R,$$
so
$$AP_A^T = BP_B^T,$$
whence
$$A(P_A^T)(P_B^T)^{-1} = B$$
so you can take $P = (P_A^T)(P_B^T)^{-1}$.